# Saving and Retrieving Python object Attributes values to a file

Tags: python, json, dictionary, file-handling

I require 2 things to be done.

> First, take the `request` object and save the object attribute values
>   to a file as values of some known keys. This file needs to be editable
>   after saving, ie, a user can modify the values of the keys(So I used
>   json format). This is handled in function
>   `save_auth_params_to_file()`.
>
> Second, get the file contents in a such a format that I can retrieve
>   the values using the keys. This is handled in function
>   `get_auth_params_from_file`.

```
import json
import os

SUCCESS_AUTH_PARAM_FILE = '/auth/success_auth_params.json'


def save_auth_params_to_file(request):

    auth_params = {}
    if request is not None:
        auth_params['token'] = request.token
        auth_params['auth_url'] = request.auth_url
        auth_params['server_cert'] = request.server_cert
        auth_params['local_key'] = request.local_key
        auth_params['local_cert'] = request.local_cert
        auth_params['timeout'] = request.timeout_secs

    with open(SUCCESS_AUTH_PARAM_FILE, 'w') as fout:
        json.dump(auth_params, fout, indent=4)


def get_auth_params_from_file():
    auth_params = {}
    if os.path.exists(SUCCESS_AUTH_PARAM_FILE):
        with open(SUCCESS_AUTH_PARAM_FILE, "r") as fin:
            auth_params = json.load(fin)

    return auth_params
```

Question:

1. Is there a more pythonic way to achieve the 2 things ?
2. Any potential issues in the code which I have overlooked?
3. Any error conditions I have to take care ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some things to be noted, yes:

i) When your `request` is `None` for some reason, you are saving an empty JSON object to your file. Maybe you'll want to write to your file only if `request` is not `None`?

```
auth_params = {}
if request is not None:
    auth_params['token'] = request.token
    auth_params['auth_url'] = request.auth_url
    auth_params['server_cert'] = request.server_cert
    auth_params['local_key'] = request.local_key
    auth_params['local_cert'] = request.local_cert
    auth_params['timeout'] = request.timeout_secs

    with open(SUCCESS_AUTH_PARAM_FILE, 'w') as fout:
        json.dump(auth_params, fout, indent=4)
```

ii) Why not create the dict all at once?

```
    auth_params = {
        'token': request.token,
        'auth_url': request.auth_url,
        'server_cert': request.server_cert,
        'local_key': request.local_key,
        'local_cert': request.local_cert,
        'timeout': request.timeout,
    }
```

iii) Make sure this file is in a SAFE location with SAFE permissions. This is sensitive data, like anything related to authentication.

iv) You are overwriting your file everytime `save_auth_params_to_file` is called. Maybe you mean to append your JSON to the file instead of overwriting? If that's the case:

```
with open(SUCCESS_AUTH_PARAM_FILE, 'a') as fout:
```